# How to "vectorize" this operation?

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have data of sample size `m` of `n x n` matrices in an `n` by `m*n` matrix call it `P`.

I also have a function, call if `f`, that operates on a fixed vector, call it `v`, and `n x n` matrices and returns a real number.

I want to to create a `1 x m` vector of real numbers, call it `d`, by operating `f` on `v` and each of the `n x n` matrices in `P`.

So, say for example, `n = 3` and `m = 6` I would want:

```
d(1) = f(v,P(:,1:3)), d(2) = f(v,P(:,4:6)), . . ., d(6) = f(v,P(:,16:18))
```

How can I do this without making a loop?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have data of sample size `m` of `nxn` matrices then won't it be `m by n*n` matrix?

Comment: What does your function do?

Comment: @Parag OP is saying he has m nxn matrices stacked side by size, so the final matrix is nx(m*n)

Comment: "I have data of sample size m of n x n matrices in an n by m*n matrix call it P"

Doesn't make sense to me. Do you have a 3d array P(n,n,m)? If not, I would save it like that and use `bsxfun()` along the third dimension (if I get the nature of your problem).

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what your `f` function do, I can only suggest pseudo-vectorized solution with ARRAYFUN:

```
d = arrayfun( @(x) f(v,P(:,x:x+2)), n-2:3:n*m );
```

It run with almost the same speed as a simple loop (which I think has clearer code):

```
d = zeros(1,m);
for k = 1:m
    d(k) = f(v,P(:,n*k-2:n*k));
end
```

Comment: This is the important thing, as you say: "which I think has clearer code". Code that will run at virtually the same speed as a loop, so why create a piece of code that will be impossible to read? Vectorization can run wild at times.

Comment: I have used the array solution already but this function has to be evaluated many times for different values of v (it is minimized with respect to v to be exact). So I'm hoping to speed things up, with a large data set (m > 75) and high dimension (n > 3) it can take over an hour to minimize. It shouldn't be an impossible task. The closest I've come (with a suggestion from another forum) is: 
P=reshape(P,n,n,m); a = 1:m; d = f(v,P(:,:,a)) but to no avail! After I vectorize I hope to evaluate the function in parallel!

Comment: If your bottleneck really is that one loop you might have better luck writing it as a MEX function. At a certain point it becomes faster to write something in C than to vectorise it in MATLAB